# How to read predefined (#define) across projects?

Tags: c++

I have 2 projects in the same solution: A is static library and B is exe. B depends on A

In B I do a declaration for a DEBUG mode. Something like `#define DEBUG`

Then I went to check if DEBUG is defined in A, if it does then do some debug printing:

```
// Code in A
#ifdef DEBUG
cout<<"debug message";
#endif
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I guess when A is built it doesn't have knowledge about B. How do we go about doing this? Basically because I have different executable project relying on A, and some of them need to print debug messages, and some don't. And yet I don't want to rebuilt A everytime I switch from B to another executable project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution is to build two A's, one for Debug and one for non-debug. Then the other projects can choose which one to link against.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The exact nature is not really debugging or not debugging, but something slightly different and can only be determined in B. I guess in that case some sort of `virtual` inheritance in B would do the job?

Comment: Actually this gives me an idea of different custom Builds. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`#define` is a [preprocessor macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)

It is expanded before compilation. Nothing you do in `B` is going to have an effect on the already compiled `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need some common header for B and A where you can define DEBUG option.
Or create some static function in B, like `isDebug`, define it depending on DEBUG and use it in A.